# rank deficient least squares with minimum $\ell_1$ norm

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

When a least square solution of a rank deficient least square problem is sought, there are multitude of solutions that give the same minimal residual vector $r=\mathbf{A}x-b$. I am familiar with Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse that picks minimum $\ell_2$-norm least square solution among these solutions  i.e. $$ x_{LS} = \mathbf{A}^{\dagger}b$$

Computing this usually involves getting the SVD of A and screening all singular vectors associated with zero singular values. Is there a similar expression that gives the minimum $\ell_1$-norm? Even if no expression can be given, is there a algorithm to compute the minimum $\ell_1$-norm among all solutions that give the minimum residual vector? This seems to be a convex optimization problem but I could be mistaken.

If it helps I am interested in a problem with column-rank deficient $\mathbf{A}$ and it has more rows than columns.

**Update**: A related problem where the residual *norm* is known can be solved via LASSO (using the homotopy approach to find the regularization parameter that matches the residual norm). LASSO indeed seems to give the minimum $\ell_1$ norm solution for the given residual norm. In this problem the residual vector is given and a minimum $\ell_1$ norm solution is sought.

**Edit**: After the comment below by @littleO I realized the mistake I was making that motivated the original question. I was planning to project the $b$ vector on to null space of $\mathbf{A}$ and call it the noise or residual vector but there could be a component of the noise vector in the range of $\mathbf{A}$ as well. So if I may change the question, how does one find out or estimate the norm of the noise?

Comment: The Lasso problem is to minimize $\|Ax-b\|_2^2 + \lambda \| x \|_1$ with respect to $x$. The parameter $\lambda > 0$ controls the tradeoff between minimizing the norm of the residual $Ax-b$ and minimizing $\| x \|_1$. You can solve Lasso problems using methods from convex optimization.

Comment: @littleO...also if you are familiar with GLMNET package, since the $\lambda$ values terminate at a certain minimum value that may not be smaller than desired residual norm, if I use glmnetpredict method to refit and get the residual norm for smaller $\lambda$, my understanding is that for that residual the solution is the minimum $\ell_1$ norm solution. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: By the way, you could also minimize $\| x \|_1$ subject to $\| Ax-b\| \leq \epsilon$ (where $\epsilon > 0$ is given in advance) using convex optimization techniques. Is that precisely the problem you'd like to solve?

Comment: @littleO...thanks for helping me think through the question (see edit for motivation behind the original question). In fact I would like to solve that very problem. Only now I would like to know given $\mathbf{A}$ and $b$, how do I estimate $\epsilon$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First solve the unconstrained least squares problem, for example by using the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse (which picks the minimum $\ell_2$-norm least square solution), or any other method. Evaluating the two-norm of the residual at that optimal value of $x$ provides the $\epsilon$.  Then solve the $\ell_1$-norm minimization problem subject to the  $\ell_2$-norm constraint.

Using the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse least squares solution, that would be

Minimize $\|x\|_1$ subject to $\|\mathbf{A}x - b\|_2 \le \|\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{\dagger}b - b\|_2$

The CVX code for this convex optimization problem is:

```
cvx_begin
variable x(n)
minimize(norm(x,1))
norm(A*x-b) <= norm(A*pinv(A)*b-b)
cvx_end
```